# Registration form using image upload by multipartFile

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angularjs-directive, mean-stack, multipartform-data

I am creating a simple registration form using MEAN. All text value of form is submitting properly but at the time of form load in browser console(controller.js) show following error

```html
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/$injector/unpr?p0=multipartFormProvider%20%3C-%20multipartForm%20%3C-%20AppCtrl
    at Error (native)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js:6:412
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js:43:84
    at Object.d [as get] (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js:40:344)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js:43:146
    at d (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js:40:344)
    at e (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js:41:78)
    at Object.invoke (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js:41:163)
    at R.instance (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js:89:203)
    at n (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js:64:374)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:13550
```

This is my **controller/controller.js**

```html
var myRegi =angular.module('myRegi',[]); 


 myRegi.controller('AppCtrl',['$scope','multipartForm', function($scope,$http,multipartForm) {
   $scope.customer = {};
    $scope.insert = function () {
        console.log($scope.user);
        console.log($scope.myFile);
       // $http.post('/regi',$scope.user,$scope.myFile);
       var uploadUrl = '/regi';
       multipartForm.post(uploadUrl, $scope.customer);
    } 
    
    myRegi.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function($parse){
 return {
  restrict: 'A',
  link: function(scope, element, attrs){
   var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
   var modelSetter = model.assign;

   element.bind('change', function(){
    scope.$apply(function(){
     modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
    })
   })
  }
 }
}])


myRegi.service('multipartForm', ['$http', function($http){
 this.post = function(uploadUrl, data){
  var fd = new FormData();
  for(var key in data)
   fd.append(key, data[key]);
  $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
   transformRequest: angular.indentity,
   headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }
  });
 }
}])
}]);
```

And this is **public/index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myRegi">
<head>
<title>Password Input Control</title>
<style>
table, th, td {
    
    border: 1px light gray;
    width: 40%;
    height: 50px;
    
    
}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>


<script src="controller/controller.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<form name="myForm" action="/regi">
    <div align="center" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <table>
        <tr>
    <td>First Name :</td>
        
  <td><input type="text" ng-model="user.Firstname" />
        </td></tr>
         &nbsp; &nbsp;
        <tr>
        <td>Last Name :</td>
        
  <td><input type="text" ng-model="user.Lastname" />
        </td></tr>
         &nbsp; &nbsp;
         <tr>
          <td>City :</td>
  <td><input type="text" ng-model="user.city" /></td>
         </tr>
         &nbsp; &nbsp;
         <tr>
             <td>Email :</td>
  <td><input type="email" ng-model="user.email" /></td>
        </tr>
        &nbsp; &nbsp;
        <tr>
        <td>User ID :</td>
            
  <td><input type="text" ng-model="user.userid" /></td>
        <tr>
    &nbsp; &nbsp;
    <tr>
        <td>Password:</td> 
  <td><input type="password" ng-model="user.password" /></td>
 &nbsp; &nbsp;
<tr>
    <td>Image : </td>
     <td><input multiple="multiple" file-model="myFile" type="file"  enctype="multipart/form-data"/></td>
        <br></tr>
        
        &nbsp; &nbsp; 
        <tr><td>
        <input type="button" value = "Submit" ng-click="insert()"></td> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
        <td> <input type="reset"></td></tr>
        </div>
    </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my **server.js**

```html
var express = require('express');
var app =  express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

var multer = require('multer');


app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));



// configure app to use bodyParser()
// this will let us get the data from a POST
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


app.use(multer({dest:__dirname+'/file/uploads/'}).any());


var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/Regis_module');
var Userschema = require('./models/dbSchema'); 

 app.post('/regi',function(req,res){
     
    var schema = new Userschema({
  FirstName  :  req.body.Firstname,
  LastName   :  req.body.Lastname,
  City       :  req.body.city,
  Email      :  req.body.email,
  Userid     :  req.body.userid,
  Password   :  req.body.password,
  myFile     :  req.body.myFile
});
      
     console.log(req.body);
     console.log(re.files);
     
  schema.save(function(err) {
            if (err)
              res.send(err);

            res.json({ message: 'Record Inserted', Firstname: req.body.Firstname, Lastname: req.body.Lastname, City:req.body.city, Email:req.body.email, 
                       Userid:req.body.userid, Password :req.body.password ,myFile : req.body.myFile });
        });
 });
     
    
app.listen(3000);
console.log("listening to port 3000");
```

This is my **mongoose schema(dbSchema.js)**

```html
var mongoose = require('mongoose');


var User = new mongoose.Schema({
   FirstName: String,
   LastName:  String,
   City    :  String,
   Email   :  String,
   Userid  :  String,
   Password:  String,
   myFile   :  { data: Buffer, contentType: String }  
    
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('user', User);
```

Please, help me how to i can solve that problem and can upload image with all details ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you defined your service and directive in the scope of controller.  follow this code and take out service and directive from controller scope..

```
var myRegi =angular.module('myRegi',[]); 


 myRegi.controller('AppCtrl',['$scope','multipartForm', function($scope, multipartForm) {
   $scope.user = {

    };
    $scope.insert = function () {
        console.log($scope.user);
        console.log($scope.myFile);
        $scope.myFile = null;
       var uploadUrl = '/regi';
       multipartForm.post(uploadUrl, $scope.user, $scope.myFile);
    } 
}]);
    myRegi.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function($parse){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
            var modelSetter = model.assign;

            element.bind('change', function(){
                scope.$apply(function(){
                    modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                })
            })
        }
    }
}]);


myRegi.service('multipartForm', ['$http', function($http){
    this.post = function(uploadUrl, data, myFile){
        var fd = new FormData();
        for(var key in data)
            fd.append(key, data[key]);
        fd.append('myFile', myFile);
        $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
            transformRequest: angular.indentity,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }
        });
    }
}]);
```

The above code will fail with $injector:unpr if multipartForm is not defined.

Comment: @Rakesh_Chand , with the help of your code i am getting details of file on browser console , but image is not storing in folder and  all fields is not storing in db . What change should i do in server.js .

Comment: what are you getting in console for this line `console.log($scope.user);`

Comment: You have initialized $scope.customer and values are in $scope.user. How can db will get data?
Change customer to user.

plus you never passed file to the service.

change in controller `multipartForm.post(uploadUrl, $scope.user, $scope.myfile);`

change in service `this.post = function(uploadUrl, data, myFile){
  var fd = new FormData();
  for(var key in data)
   fd.append(key, data[key]);
               fd.append('myFile', myFile);
  $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
   transformRequest: angular.indentity,
   headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }
  });
 }`

Comment: I got what you say and change as you show . At the time print all record  from the server.js  getting all record correctly but image is undefind.   Have need to change either in server.js. or dbSchema.

Comment: Can you edit your question or add all the updated code in new answer ? I don't see any problem in nodejs side.

Comment: Also i want to show file extension but its is showing "1de1d35385934553c8e89bf5d8726ad5" that type of name. So how to i can show file extension like jpg/png in uploads folder ?